# Access token missing or malformed

Tags: office365

When I try to add a connected O365 service, after logging in with the VS API tools, I get the following error message

Microsoft Visual Studio

The Connected Services component 'Office 365 APIs' failed: (HRESULT:0x80131509) Access Token missing or malformed.

OK

Anyone else come across this issue? I'd love to do some O365 integration into my app, but I'm being blocked by this issue at the moment.

Comment: did you find what was causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by using my 'onmicrosoft.com' user instead of Microsoft account user. There is some related guidance here whereby it is suggested you should only switch to a Microsoft account user when "you finish creating your apps and want to sign on to the Seller Dashboard and publish them to the Office Store": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605899(v=office.15).aspx#bk_Office365Account.

I hope this helps!